# Google VR sdk won't compile

Tags: google-cardboard, google-vr

When I add the sdk to my project and try to compile, I get these errors:

> Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/GvrViewer.cs(84,18): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name StereoController' could not be found. Are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?
>   Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/GvrViewer.cs(171,11): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace nameGvrProfile' could not be found. Are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?
>   Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/GvrViewer.cs(188,11): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name GvrProfile' could not be found. Are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?
>   Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/GvrViewer.cs(192,18): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace nameBaseVRDevice' could not be found. Are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?
>   Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/GvrViewer.cs(69,17): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name StereoController' could not be found. Are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?
>   Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/GvrViewer.cs(157,10): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace nameGvrProfile' could not be found. Are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?
>   Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/GvrViewer.cs(174,10): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name GvrProfile' could not be found. Are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?
>   Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/GvrViewer.cs(253,10): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace nameGvrProfile' could not be found.

Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 1.0 on, the GVR Unity SDK is targeted at the native integration (now in technical preview). If you are using a version w/ out technical preview, then you need some extra scripts, which are in the "backwards compat" package.